# rank of a matrix with full rank sub matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Consider an $n \times p, (n>p)$ matrix$X=[A,B,C]$ where $A$ is $n \times p_A$, $B$ is $n \times p_B$ and $C$ is $n \times p_C$ with $n=n_A+n_B+n_C$. Assume that submatrices $[A,B]$, $[B,C]$ and $[A,C]$ are all of full column rank.  In this case, can we say that $X$ is of full column rank?

Or more generally, for a matrix $Z=[Z_1,...Z_m]$, can we say that $Z$ is of full column rank if $[Z_i,Z_j]$ are of full column rank for all $i \neq j$?

Comment: The lack of context for your problem will suggest to some Readers that you are simply passing through an exercise without suitably digesting its meaning.  Did you (for example) try to construct matrices $A,B,C$ that satisfy the hypotheses but not the conclusion?  Even some observations about the outlines of such potential counterexamples would be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

No it’s not true. The problem is that columns of $C$ can be linear combination of columns of $A$ and $B$. An example is

$$X:=\begin{pmatrix} 
   1 & 0 & 1 \\
  0 & 1 & 1 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

and let $A:= \begin{pmatrix} 
   1  \\
  0 \\
  0 \\
  0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$, $B:= \begin{pmatrix} 
   0  \\
  1 \\
  0 \\
  0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$, $C:=  \begin{pmatrix} 
   1  \\
  1 \\
  0 \\
  0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Thanks! I understand the problem.

Comment: @user0131 you’re welcome 